# Building a WSP File on the Build Machine

Tags: sharepoint, vsewss

On my development machine I installed **VSeWSS 1.3** and configured the local IIS 6 so that I can **build** my SharePoint project and **deploy** the **generated WSP** file to the local machine. The WSP file is generated by the Packaging step, which I can successfully install on other machines.

Now I have to **migrate my project to our build machine** which currently does not have SharePoint installed and is not configured for VSeWSS (no VSeWSS web service endpoint). **Is there a way to automate the building of the WSP file without the need to configure IIS on the build machine for use with SharePoint and VSeWSS?**

Some of the books describe the **manual step** of using **MakeCab.exe and defining a DDF** file, but I don't see any **DDF file generated by VSeWSS** (is it maybe generated in a TEMP folder which I could use to configure my automated build process?).

Comment: It looks like the contents of the pkg folder which is generated by the build step might be useful when building a DDF file by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just faced the same problem. I opted for another tool for developing the whole solution: I found `WSPBuilder` much cleaner and less intrusive.  It also can be used from the Command line, which is great for Build files.

I modified some Nant scripts created by [Bil Simser](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/) in order to compile and deploy the project and move the code from VSeWSS to WSPBuilder. It works like a charm either on my machine or on the build machine.

You can find WSPBuilder on [http://www.Codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com), and these targets need nantContrib (on [www.tigris.org](http://www.tigris.org)) to work.

Here are some of the targets I'm using:

```
<target name="build" depends="compile">
  <copy todir="${build.dir}\12\">
    <fileset basedir="${sharepoint.dir}\12">
      <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
  <copy
    file="${sharepoint.dir}\solutionid.txt"
    tofile="${build.dir}\solutionid.txt"
  />
  <call target="buildsolutionfile" />
</target>



<target name="buildsolutionfile">
    <exec program="${wspbuilder.exe}" workingdir="${build.dir}">

      <arg value="-BuildDDF"/>
      <arg value="${debug}"/>

      <arg value="-Cleanup"/>
      <arg value="false"/>

      <arg value="-FolderDestination"/>
      <arg value="${build.dir}"/>

      <arg value="-Outputpath"/>
      <arg value="${build.dir}"/>

      <arg value="-TraceLevel"/>
      <arg value="verbose"/>
    </exec>
    <copy
      file="${build.dir}\${package.file}"
      tofile="${solution.dir}\${package.file}"/>
  </target>



 <target name="addsolution">
    <exec program="${stsadm.exe}" verbose="${verbose}">
      <arg value="-o" />
      <arg value="addsolution" />
      <arg value="-filename" />
      <arg value="${solution.dir}\${package.file}" />
    </exec>
    <call target="spwait" />
  </target>

  <target name="spwait" description="Waits for the timer job to complete.">
    <exec program="${stsadm.exe}" verbose="${verbose}">
      <arg value="-o" />
      <arg value="execadmsvcjobs" />
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="app.pool.reset" description="Resets Sharepoint's application pool.">
    <iisapppool action="Restart" pool="${apppool}" server="${server}" />
  </target>
  <target name="deploysolution" depends="addsolution">
    <exec program="${stsadm.exe}" workingdir="${build.dir}"  verbose="${verbose}">
      <arg value="-o" />
      <arg value="deploysolution" />
      <arg value="-name" />
      <arg value="${package.file}" />
      <arg value="-immediate" />
      <arg value="-allowgacdeployment" />
      <arg value="-allcontenturls" />
      <arg value="-force" />
    </exec>
    <call target="spwait" />
    <call target="app.pool.reset" />

  </target>
```

Comment: WSP Builder is Quick,clean and Rocks